# Prevent the first state of component of null after recover data from child component in parent component in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to pass some data from child component to parent component with a handleChange function, but the first state that I recovered is always null, I need to prevent this.

```
//PARENT COMPONENT
class FormOpen extends React.Component  {
    constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
    }

    handleChange(value){
      this.setState({
          active: value
      })
    }

    render(){
        return(
          <form>
              <CheckSelectBox change={this.handleChange} />
          </form>
        )
    }
}


//CHILD COMPONENT
class CheckSelectBox extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
      super(props);
      this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this);
      this.state = {
        active: false,
      }
  }

  handleClick(event) {
      const currentState = this.state.active;
      this.setState({ active: !currentState, checked: !currentState });
      this.props.change(this.state.active);  
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div onClick={this.handleClick}>
        <input type="checkbox" />
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

For exemple, if I print in parent component:

```
console.log(this.state.active);
```

after change I will receive the first state null, someone could help me?

Comment: `state = { active: false }` in the `FormOpen` component maybe?

Comment: https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#setstate

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In react `this.setState` works asynchronously, means setState does not update state immediately.

Solution -> `this.setState()` got a callback that fires after the state is updated.

So something like this in `handleClick`

```
this.setState({ active: !currentState, checked: !currentState }, () => {
  this.props.change(this.state.active);
);
```

Comment: Thank you for the amazing solution. If I need to retrieve the name of an input in the child component. Can you tell me how can I do?

Comment: the name attribute of input tag `<input name="some-input"/>` ? there is a good read in react's documentation https://reactjs.org/docs/forms.html#handling-multiple-inputs